# PowerShell Remote script exiting, but not exiting parent script

Tags: powershell, teamcity

Below is a script we are using in TeamCity. We are sporadically getting a hung build during this step and some others similarly written. From what I've been able to find out is that the error is occurring between the two servers.

The script creates a remote session and executes on the remote machine. The remote script completes successfully, but never causes this script to exit which leads to a build step hanging.

```
$username = '%SvcAcct%'
$password = '%SvcAcctPwd%'
$credentials = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential `
-ArgumentList @($username,(ConvertTo-SecureString -String $password -AsPlainText -Force))



$remoteSession = New-PSSession -ComputerName %RemoteServer% -Authentication Credssp -Credential $credentials


Invoke-Command -FilePath %teamcity.build.checkoutDir%\NovoDeploy\Powershell\InstallNovo.ps1 `
-ArgumentList "C:\NovoDeploy\Installers","C:\NovoDeploy\%InstallSettingsConfigFileName%","%SvcAcctPwd%" -Session $remoteSession


#Get the exit code from the remote session so 
#we can pass it through to TeamCity and fail the build.

$remoteSessionExitCode = Invoke-Command { $lastexitcode } -Session $remoteSession

exit $remoteSessionExitCode
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using `remove-pssession -$remoteSession` at the end of your script.

`Remove-PSSession`closes one or more Windows PowerShell sessions (PSSessions). I'm thinking maybe your exit command is just exiting the remote powershell session you use to run the remote command and then continuing as a local powershell session after your `exit`. If you add `remove-pssession` after you assign the exitcode variable, then maybe your `exit`command will exit the local terminal as needed.

Just a theory but it's worth testing out.

Comment: What is the purpose for this/why would this be needed? Also would that need to be added before or after the exit command?

Comment: @ace Edited my answer.